# Double increment where 2nd increment reflects 1st in sql for encounter data

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I am building healthcare 837 encounters and need to set increments on the HL segments.

- `C1` based on what is set on `Criteria1` and `C2` based on `Criteria2`.
- `C2` will never have the same number as `C1` and vice versa.
- `C1` I was able to pull using `row_number() over(order by (select Criteria1))`

It's the `C2` I am having a problem with.

```
 C1 | C2 | Criteria1 | Criteria2
  1 | 2 | ID1 | NID1
  1 | 3 | ID1 | NID2
  1 | 4 | ID1 | NID3
  5 | 6 | ID2 | NID4
  5 | 7 | ID2 | NID5
  5 | 8 | ID2 | NID6
  9 |10 | ID3 | NID7
```

Simplified query:

```
 SELECT cm.Criteria1, cm.Criteria2, cj.C1 
 FROM [dbo].[TBL1] cm 
 JOIN (
         SELECT cm.Criteria1,
                row_number() over(order by (select Criteria1)) as C1 
         FROM [dbo].[TBL1] cm 
         GROUP BY cm.Criteria1) cj on cj.Criteria1 = cm.Criteria1 
 GROUP BY cm.Criteria1, cm.Criteria2, cj.C1 Order by cj.C1
```

Comment: Show us your code to help you

Comment: Simplified-SELECT  cm.Criteria1
  ,cm.Criteria2
  ,cj.C1
 FROM [dbo].[TBL1] cm
  JOIN (SELECT cm.Criteria1
    ,row_number() over(order by (select Criteria1)) as C1
    FROM [dbo].[TBL1] cm
    group by cm.Criteria1) cj
   on cj.Criteria1 = cm.Criteria1
Group by cm.Criteria1
  ,cm.Criteria2
  ,cj.C1
Order by cj.C1

Comment: Please, add definition of your TBL1 table with example of data it can have, also, please add desired output for sample data.

Comment: What version  of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: The output is listed above in Columns c1 and c2 where criteria1 and 2 are the Values that change. C1 needs to add 1 where C2 left off. I am using SQL 2014.

Comment: @Vader you are not showing source record set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work but I didn't check many edge cases (fun with windowing!):

```
with tbl1 as (
    select 'ID1' as Criteria1, 'NID1' as Criteria2
    union
    select 'ID1', 'NID2'
    union
    select 'ID2', 'NID4'
    union
    select 'ID2', 'NID5'
    union
    select 'ID3', 'NID7'
)

select 
    rank() over (order by Criteria1) + DENSE_ranK() OVER (ORDER BY CRITERIA1) - 1 as C1,
    rank() over (order by Criteria1) + row_number() over (partition by Criteria1 order by Criteria2) + DENSE_ranK() OVER (ORDER BY CRITERIA1) - 1 as C2,
    Criteria1,
    Criteria2
from
  tbl1
```

To break it down a little:

Let's call each set of Criteria1 rows a "partition" as in SQL parlance.

The requirement is thus:

C1 is always equal to the number of rows in all the previous partitions + 1 for the current partition, plus the number of previous partitions.

C2 is always equal to the number of rows in all the previous partitions + 1 for the current partition, plus the number of previous partitions, plus the number of all the previous rows within the partition + 1 for the current row.

`RANK() over (order by Criteria1)` gives you the number of rows in all the previous partitions + 1.

`DENSE_RANK() over (order by Criteria1) - 1` gives you the number of previous partitions.

`ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Criteria1 order by Criteria2)` gives you the number of previous rows within the partition.

Comment: The rank and Dense rank worked perfect, thank you Kyle! This will come in handy for any EDI specialist building X12 data sets.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what exactly you are trying to get, but it seems below is what you are looking for:

```
with counts as (select count(distinct cm.criteria1) c1, count(distinct cm.criteria2) c2 from dbo.tbl1) 
select cj1.c1, cj2.c2, cm.criteria1, cm.criteria2
from dbo.tbl1 cm
inner join ( 
      select cm1.criteria1, 
         row_number() over ( order by cm1.criteria1)as c1 
      from dbo.tbl1 cm1 group by cm1.criteria1) cj1 
              on cj1.criteria1 = cm.criteria1
inner join ( 
      select cm2.criteria2, 
         (select counts.c1 from counts) + row_number() over ( order by cm2.criteria2) as c2 
      from dbo.tbl1 cm2 group by cm1.criteria2) cj2 
              on cj2.criteria2 = cm.criteria2
group by cm.criteria1, cm.criteria2, cj1.c1, cj2.c2
order by cj1.c1, cj2.c2
```